# Is there a multiple-and-add formula in Google's spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

What I want is to easily multiply a number by another number for each column and add them up at the end in Google Sheets. For example:

```
User | Points 1 | Points 2 | Points 3 | Total
     |     5    |     1    |     4    |
-----+----------+----------+----------+------
Jane |        2 |        3 |        0 |   13 (2*5 + 3*1 + 0*4)
John |        1 |       11 |        4 |   32 (1*5 + 11*1 + 4*4)
```

So it's easy enough to make this formula for the total:

```
= B3*$B$2 + C3*$C$2 + D3*$D$2
```

The problem is I frequently need to insert additional columns or even remove some columns. So then I have to mess with all the formulas. It's a pain... we have many spreadsheets with these formulas. I wish there was a formula like `SUM(B3:D3)` where I could just specify a range. Is there anything like `MULTIPLY_AND_SUM(B2:D2, B3:D3)` that would do this? Then I could insert columns in the middle and the range would still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that without requiring a special-purpose function.

In `E3`, try this (and copy it to the rest of your rows):

```
=sum(arrayformula(B3:D3*B$2:D$2))
```

You can read about `arrayformula` [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291?hl=en).

As long as you introduce new columns between `B` and `D`, this formula will automatically adjust. If you add new columns outside of that range, you'll need to edit (and cut & paste).

On it's own, `arrayformula(B3:D3*B$2:D$2)` operates over each value in `B3:D3` in turn, multiplying it by the corresponding value in `B$2:D$2`. (Note the use of absolute references to 'lock down' to row 2.) The result in this case is three values, `[10,3,0]`, arranged horizontally in three rows because that matches the dimensions of the ranges.

The enveloping `sum()` function adds up the values of the array produced by `arrayformula`, which is `13` in this case.

As you copy that formula to other rows, the relative range references get updated for the new row.

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in function in Google Sheets that does exactly what you are looking for: SUMPRODUCT.
In your example the formula would be:

```
=sumproduct(B$2:D$2,B3:D3)
```

Click [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) for more information about this function.